# C progam to play audio file in Linux crackels at end

Tags: c, linux

On Ubuntu Linux I have written a c program based on the Libao example program to open audio wave file and play. It works fine but at the end  after finish playing there is crackling high pitch noise. Here is the code which I modified mt libao example. How can I fix it? Please help

```
 #include <stdio.h>  
 #include <string.h>  
 #include <ao/ao.h>  
 #include <math.h>  
 #define BUF_SIZE 4096 

int main(int argc, char **argv)  
{  
 ao_device *device;  
 ao_sample_format format;  
 int default_driver;  
 char *buffer;  
 int buf_size;  
 int sample;  
 FILE *fp;

 float freq = 440.0;  
 int i;  
 /* -- Initialize -- */  
 fprintf(stderr, "libao example program\n");  
 ao_initialize();  
 /* -- Setup for default driver -- */  
 default_driver = ao_default_driver_id();  
 memset(&format, 0, sizeof(format));  
 format.bits = 16;  
 format.channels = 2;  
 format.rate = 44100;  
 format.byte_format = AO_FMT_LITTLE;  
 /* -- Open driver -- */  
// device = ao_open_live(default_driver, &format, NULL /* no options */);  
device = ao_open_live(default_driver, &format, NULL /* no options */);  

 if (device == NULL) {  
     fprintf(stderr, "Error opening device.\n");  
     return 1;  
 }  


 fp = fopen("nc.wav", "rb");
 if (fp == NULL) {
 fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file \n");
  return;
  }

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
unsigned long fileLen = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

//Allocate memory
buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);

if (!buffer)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
                            fclose(fp);
    return;
}



 fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, fp);
 fclose(fp);

ao_play(device, buffer, buf_size);  
 /* -- Close and shutdown -- */  
 ao_close(device);  
 ao_shutdown();  
return (0);  
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `buf_size`

Comment: HI Samgak,  Thank you for the prompt reply. You are correct. You saved my day. I added the following and it is working fine now.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 buf_size = format.bits/8 * format.channels * format.rate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `buf_size` variable is passed to `ao_play` without being initialized, and the crackles most likely occur because it is playing past the end of the sample buffer into random memory.

Depending on your compiler settings, the compiler can warn you about uninitialized variables bugs like this ([gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) only does it when optimizations are turned on, via the `-Wuninitialized` or `-Wall` settings).

Comment: Thank you Samgak. Further I also changed the  default driver to on libao.conf file to pulse and every thing is working fine since then. Thank you for your help.